# Azkaban: pass parameters to underlying job code

Tags: azkaban

Is it possible to pass options from a azkaban work flow to the underlying job code?

I have something like this, It kind of works for hard coded/pre-known dates but I would like to have the option to specify the date when I execute the flow:

```
from azkaban import Job, Project
import datetime
import os
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta




options = {
            'start.date' : today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), # Can we pass this as an argument to the underlying code?
            'day.offset' : 1
            }

project = Project('my_project',root=__file__)
project.add_file('my_shell_script.sh', 'my_shell_script.sh')
project.add_job('my_job', Job(options, {'type' : 'command' : 'bash my_shell_script <pass date here?>'}))
project.add_job('my_job', Job(options, {'type' : 'command' : 'java -jar test.jar <pass date here?>'}))
```

Thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 5):

### Big Picture: make the parameter persistent by writing it to disk

One way to pass parameters between nonadjacent jobs in an Azkaban flow is to operate on the JOB_OUTPUT_PROP_FILE just before you need the parameter. *It is necessary to do this using a shell script because the JOB_OUTPUT_PROP_FILE variable is not directly available to a given job.* 
This approach writes the relevant information to a file and read it just before it is needed using a helper script.  Parameters can be passed to adjacent jobs by writing to the JOB_OUTPUT_PROP_FILE at each step.

[image: Pass parameters between jobs diagram]

---

### Concept

1. write a file to disk that contains the information you wish to pass
2. create a helper/preparation shell script that runs just before the job that needs the parameter
3. use the parameter in your job

---

### Example

In a scenario where the date when the first job in a flow was run needs to be used by a latter job, first write the relevant data to file.  In this example, the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format is written to a local file called rundate.text

```
#step_1.job
type=command
dependencies=initialize_jobs
command=whoami
command.1=/bin/sh -c "date '+%Y-%m-%d' > rundate.text"
```

Then, just before the parameter is needed, run a prep script to make the parameter available.

```
#step_4_preparation.job
type=command
dependencies=step_3
command=whoami
command.1=/bin/bash rd.sh
```

step 4 preparation executes the following shell script (rd.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh
# this script takes the run_date value from the text file and passes it to Azkaban
# Now, the variable can be used in the next step of the job

RD=$(cat rundate.text)

echo "Now setting Job Output Property File with RD (run date) variable"
echo $RD


#This is the point where the parameter is written in JSON format
#to the JOB_OUTPUT_PROP_FILE, which allows it to be used in the next step
echo '{"RD" : "'"$RD"'"}' > "${JOB_OUTPUT_PROP_FILE}"
```

Then, in the following step, the parameter can be used, which is ${RD} in this example.

```
# step_4.job
type=command
dependencies=step_4_preparation
command=whoami
command.1=bash -c "echo ${RD} is the run date"
```

Answer (score 2):

Well,

As per azkaban doc's only global flow properties can be overridden.
In python, we can set global properties in this way:

```
    project = Project('emr-cluster-creation', root=__file__)

project.properties = {
                                                    'emr.cluster.name' : 'default-clustername',
                                                    'emr.master.instance.type' : 'r3.xlarge',
                                                    'emr.core.instance.type' : 'r3.xlarge',
                                                    'emr.task.instance.type' : 'r3.xlarge',
                                                    'emr.instance.count' : 11,
                                                    'emr.task.instance.count' : 5,
                                                    'emr.hadoop.conf.local.path' : 's3n://bucket/hadoop-configuration.json',
                                                    'emr.hive.site.s3.path' : 's3n://bucket/hive-site.xml',
                                                    'emr.spark.version' : '1.4.0.b',
#                                                   'emr.service.role' : 'some-role', #amazon IAM role.
                                                    'emr.service.role' : '\'\'', #amazon IAM role.
                                                    'emr.cluster.output' : '\'\''
    }

# do something...
```

These parameters could be passed to the underlying app/scripts as ${emr.cluster.name}. This would support both default property values to be passed and the override the flow parameters either on azkaban server web-ui or using azkaban ajax API.

Answer (score 1):

As [eeasterly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200465/4367538) said the correct way is to use the `JOB_OUTPUT_PROP_FILE` but instead of persisting it to the file system, I believe it is better to use the trait that it is passed to all its dependencies ([Creating Flows > Job configuration > Parameter Output > "Properties can be exported to be passed to its dependencies"](https://azkaban.github.io/azkaban/docs/latest/#job-configuration)).

To leverage this feature just make the jobs that need the exported parameters dependencies of the job that exports them. In eeasterly's case discard the intermediate `step 4 preparation` and just make the `step 4` dependant on `step 1`.